# Sort an integer array by converting an element to its sum of numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

### The question I am given is

We are given an array.

In one operation we can replace any element of the array with any two elements that sum to that element.
For example: `array` = `{4, 11, 7}`. In one operation you can replace `array[1]` with `5` and `6` which sums to `11`. So the array becomes array = `{4, 5, 6, 7}`

Return the *minimum number of steps* in which the whole array can be sorted in non-decreasing order. Along with array in sorted order.

For example: `array` = `{3,9,3}`

**I think the answer will be `9` will be converted to `3,3,3`**

But I cannot think of a general formula of doing it.

### My thoughts on the solution are

Suppose we want to convert number 6 and 9

We use if and else

**IF**

we see that we divide a number by 2 and take ceiling but it is greater than the number on it's right side(last example in the question) then we keep subtracting that number(3) until we get integer 0.

That is 9 = 3(number on right of 9 in array in last example) - 3 - 3

**ELSE**

simply do ceiling(num / 2) to get first number and then num - ceil(num / 2) to ger second. 7 will be 4 and 3.

Please can someone think of a general formula for doing it?

Comment: `[5, 6, 7]` is already sorted in non-decreasing order.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a Q&A site, not a homework service. Please take the [tour] and read the [help], and see [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/) You are expected to do your own work, and ask **specific** questions as needed. So, what exactly have you tried so far that is not working for you? "*I cannot think of a general formula of doing it*" means you haven't even come up with a solution before you can begin coding it, so why are you asking this on a coding site?

Comment: Is this online for testing somewhere? Or do you have a larger test case for us?

Comment: Hi, The test case is [12, 9,3,7,6,17,19,21], this will then convert to 12 will convert to 3,3,3,3 and 9 will convert to 3,3,3,3 and 7 to 3 and 4. There can be other combinations as long as the number cannot be further divided

Comment: Hey y’all. • `[7 115 9]` • `[5 8 7]` • This is not an easy question, don’t fall into traps with easy answers. The point is to do it in _the fewest_ steps possible. Might I suggest... thinking _backwards_ from the worst possible decomposition?

Comment: That's true @Dúthomhas. Also there doesn't seem any specific formula just we divide and make pairs till we do not need any more division.

Comment: There is a good solution.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Are you saying the current answers are wrong?

Comment: I didn’t say any such thing.

Comment: @Dúthomhas Ok, that's just what your *"don’t fall into traps with easy answers"* sounded like to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to scan from the right to the left. For convenient explanation, let's mark the right-most element `x_0`, and the left-most `x_{n-1}` (n can increase as you split a number into two).

If `x_{i} > x_{i-1}`, you would want to divide `x_{i}` into `((x_{i} - 1) / x_{i-1}) + 1` parts, where `/` is integer division, as evenly as possible.

So for example:

- If `x_{i} = 15`, `x_{i-1] = 5`, divide `x_{i}` into `(15-1)/5 + 1 = 3` parts: `(5, 5, 5)`.
- If `x_{i} = 19`, `x_{i-1] = 5`, divide `x_{i}` into `(19-1)/5 + 1 = 4` parts: `(4, 5, 5, 5)`.

(To divide a number equally into a non-decreasing sequence would require a bit of calculation, which shouldn't be too difficult.)

Once you know the sequence, it would be straightforward to repeatedly split a number into 2 to produce that sequence.

Comment: *"To divide a number equally into a non-decreasing sequence would require a bit of calculation"* - Isn't it simply a division? In your example you want to divide 19 into 4 parts,  and `19 / 4` gives you `4` (the smallest part, the only one you need to know).

Comment: You are a genius by the way!

Answer (score 2):

[Edy's way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331048/12671057) (as I interpret it) in Python:

```python
def solve(xs):
    limit = 10**100
    out = []
    for x in reversed(xs):
        parts = (x - 1) // limit + 1
        limit, extra = divmod(x, parts)
        out += extra * [limit+1] + (parts - extra) * [limit]
    print(len(out) - len(xs), out[::-1])

solve([4, 11, 7])
solve([3, 9, 3])
solve([9, 4, 15, 15, 28, 23, 13])
```

Output showing steps and result array for the three test cases ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY/RCoMwDEXf/Yr72GplZm5sE/Yl4sPAjhWcldqJ@3qXWnGBQHNzcpMOX/@yfXkd3LK0@onRdpMW8yirBBydeRuPO6hIUyqKVbOfoNTNWjytwwzTw@lJu1G3/9kQw8P5kWkxIwdJHA6bZQbaoVVR0LN3D2ZbM70t@6g4LXcuLM7uG5eiXucyathMxEV5bMq9G48cnOm96HQv2EIyFZ58pwqWdVXl1MgkiV@vTwpECheWNqVUuCmUf4GrQJ1jHq@czBATy/ID)):

```
1 [4, 5, 6, 7]
2 [3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
8 [3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
```

An output illustrating the progress:

```
[4, 11, 7] = (input)
[4, 11, [7]]
[4, [5, 6], [7]]
[[4], [5, 6], [7]]

[3, 9, 3] = (input)
[3, 9, [3]]
[3, [3, 3, 3], [3]]
[[3], [3, 3, 3], [3]]

[9, 4, 15, 15, 28, 23, 13] = (input)
[9, 4, 15, 15, 28, 23, [13]]
[9, 4, 15, 15, 28, [11, 12], [13]]
[9, 4, 15, 15, [9, 9, 10], [11, 12], [13]]
[9, 4, 15, [7, 8], [9, 9, 10], [11, 12], [13]]
[9, 4, [5, 5, 5], [7, 8], [9, 9, 10], [11, 12], [13]]
[9, [4], [5, 5, 5], [7, 8], [9, 9, 10], [11, 12], [13]]
[[3, 3, 3], [4], [5, 5, 5], [7, 8], [9, 9, 10], [11, 12], [13]]
```

Code for that ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBBboMwEEX3nOLvgomj4JKotFJOglggMVEsBYNsB7mbXp0ONklqaRbz/ebJ4@nH30ZT1ZNdlp6ucON9pjw48Z2Bz2S18dxK7C7ItZkeXuxEvLrrQXtcoMqiUGUZs@tooSUCtAGZx0C285Rbmsk66lft5o3uznrHgjzgACVwPG7OPdQLiokEBW87Zns9DyOLZJoWLy645le3qy1pD2lEoEATHS1rk@WZ7FX7fsu2p/i3tciy9BvNSUIpic9WPJNK4kuiegfcrdQ51UfNxYxiYln@AA)):

```python
def solve(xs):
    print(xs, '= (input)')
    limit = 10**100
    for i, x in enumerate(reversed(xs)):
        parts = (x - 1) // limit + 1
        limit, extra = divmod(x, parts)
        xs[~i] = (parts - extra) * [limit] + extra * [limit+1]
        print(xs)
    print()
```

Comment: I think that's the answer.

Comment: But it needs to return the array also which it changed.

Comment: @programcggg Oh. When I reread the spec for that, I stopped reading at *"Return the minimum number of steps in which the whole array can be sorted in non-decreasing order."* Didn't see the following *"Along with array in sorted order."* That's highly unusual. Normally, only one of the two things is requested. Oh well, fairly easy to produce the array as well.

Comment: oh yep. All good, but you have done it brilliantly. Thanks!!

Comment: @programcggg Note the update I just posted. Partly it's unusual that both things are requested because the number of steps can trivially be computed from the array (as I did now in the new code). That's not a challenge, just a nuisance.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Amazing solution. Thank you again. This is very clean way of doing this.

Comment: Absolutely right about your comment regarding number if steps. True. Thanks again