# C++ Memory leak error when resizing C++ dynamic array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, heap-memory

The code below converts lets say array 3,9,3 to sorted array of integers 3,3,3,3,3 by converting 9 into sum of maximum possible parts.

The link to code/algorithm used in this code is answered at

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75331557/21145472

I am struck in this C++ code. When I ran it yesterday it was fine but today it gives memory leak error when function resizeArray() is run third time.

Please help fix this memory leak

```
#include<cmath>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

void resizeArray(int *orig, int size, int newSize) {
        int *resized = new int[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i ++)
            resized[i] = orig[i];
        delete [] orig;
        orig = resized;
}

int main(){
    int n = 3;
    int *arr = new int[n];
    int arrLength = n;
    arr[0] = 3;
    arr[1] = 9;
    arr[2] = 3;
    int *arrSorted = new int[0];
    int sortedArrayLength = 0;
    int temp;
    unsigned long long int limit = 10e4;
    long long parts = 0;
    int extra = 0;
    int mainArrayIndex = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i<n/2; i++){
        temp = arr[i];
        arr[i] = arr[n-i-1];
        arr[n-i-1] = temp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        parts = floor((arr[i] - 1) / (limit)) + 1;
        limit = arr[i] / parts;
        extra = arr[i] % parts;

        for(int index = 0; index < extra; index++){
            resizeArray(arrSorted, sortedArrayLength, sortedArrayLength + 1);

            arrSorted[mainArrayIndex] =     limit+1;
            mainArrayIndex+=1;
            sortedArrayLength+=1;
        }


        for(int index = 0; index < parts - extra; index++){
            resizeArray(arrSorted, sortedArrayLength, sortedArrayLength + 1);
            arrSorted[mainArrayIndex] =     limit;
            mainArrayIndex+=1;
            sortedArrayLength+=1;
        }

    }

    cout << "Array sorted steps taken" << " " << sortedArrayLength - arrLength;
    cout << endl;

    for(int i = 0; i < sortedArrayLength; i++){
        if(i == 0)
            cout <<  "[";

        cout << arrSorted[i];
        if(i < sortedArrayLength - 1)
            cout << ", ";

        if(i == sortedArrayLength - 1)
            cout << "]";
    }

    delete []arr;
    delete []arrSorted;

}
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector` ?

Comment: `int *arrSorted = new int[0];` - doesn't look right.

Comment: It was specifically intended to be used arrays only. Yes vector would do better and I think even STL arrays may b :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your helper function's `orig = resized;` doesn't reassign your main function's `arrSorted` as you intend. Use a reference:

```
void resizeArray(int *&orig, ...) {
```

(That and the lack of including `iostream` are the only correctness issues I see, and this fix got rid of the error.)

Comment: Thanks heaps! I now know why we have technology in the world, because of people like you. Thanks again! Dumb me

Comment: May be I can put link to the previous question about the algorithm used which you coded.

Comment: @noobinallman Yes, would make the question clearer. Maybe link directly to my answer, though  (click on "Share" under it to get a link).